Binding an ItemClick Event on a Parent Window to a BarButtonItem on a child UserControl
I have a parent window (windowMain) that has a child UserControl (userOne) and another UserControl (userTwo) within userOne.
windowMain has a BarButtonItem and I need to bind that ItemClick event to a BarButtonItem ItemClick event on the Child's Child UserControl userTwo.
As a work around I have created a hidden ToggleButton on userTwo that runs the method of the UserControl's BarButtonItem.
From windowMain, I can easily find this hidden ToggleButton on the UserControl (using VisualTreeHelper) and run the method via the hidden ToggleButton's IsChecked Event.
This works well, but as a new WPF programmer it seems unnecessary to have hidden buttons to do this, so here's my first question on this site:
Is there a way to directly bind the parent BarButtonItem ItemClick event to the userTwo BarButtonItem ItemClickEvent?
While there is a ton of advice on binding but I can't find a specific solution to this scenario from Parent to a Child's Child.

It is a bit unclear what exactly you are asking here. First of all, attaching an event handler method has nothing to do with data binding. Then it should be obvious that neither the inner, nested UserControl should have knowledge of the parent Window of its parent UserControl, nor vice versa. The outer UserControl may expose a method that is called in an event handler in the MainWindow class. That method could in turn call a method of the inner UserControl.

You should however take a look at MVVM and the ICommand interface. The BarButtonItem's Command property could be bound to a view model command which may somehow notify the inner UserControl.

Do you want to execute the event handler registered with BarButtonItem of  the userTwo when the BarButtonItem of windowMain was clicked? Can you please update your question to explain your problem a little bit better?

And what is the event handler in userTwo doing? I'm just asking to find out whether the event handler is in the correct class. It appears like the event handler should have been defined in the Window.

@BionicCode Yes, that is precisely what I attempting to do. I want to execute the event handler registered with the BarButtonItem of userTwo when the BarButtonItem of windowMain is clicked.
There are several buttons each running different methods such as opening/closing/saving documents. The control I'm using (on userTwo) has embedded buttons which I need to access from windowMain.

@Clemens Thank you. Ok, that makes sense and no wonder I could not find an example of binding the event handler. My solution which is working will then suffice. Thank you for pointing me in the direction of the ICommand interface - I will look into that as well.

Based on the additional context you have provided I suggest refactoring your design and use routed commands.
It should be noted that the commonly recommended approach to develop WPF applications is to implement the MVVM design pattern. In this context, the solution could look different. You can still use routed commands, but the invoked data related logic (open/close documents) would not be implemented in UI related classes (e.g. controls).
It really doesn't get well when you move data logic to nested child control(s). You likely end up with duplicate code. Such logic should reside in a single place (e.g., a common parent) that does not introduce weird dependencies. For example, it's ok to have your child control to depend on the parent Window. But it will become smelly if the parent knows details about its children in order to be able to do its job. It's also bad if control A has to know control B only to execute some action.
In general, "unimportant" child controls must not implement any application relevant logic. A good way to enable them to trigger such application scope operations is to introduce normal commands, routed commands or routed events.  For example, there should be a single place in your application where data is read from or written to a file. Then all classes that need this functionality can use it.
And a parent control should not know details about its child controls, especially when the children are dynamic. For example, the class that implements file read/write functionalities must not know the clients of this functionality. It must not observe its clients to know when to execute. Instead, the clients must tell when and what they want to execute.
A Popup does not open itself by accessing the child control. A Popup is opened by the child control by using the parent's API to open it. The Popup doesn't know about its child. It just knows that it has a child.
The following example shows how you can move the application logic to a class that is actually a common parent of all controls that will depend on the same functionality. If you are developing UI driven, then this class could be the root Window or a class that is used by the Window.
MainWindow.xaml.cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public static readonly RoutedCommand OpenDocumentCommand = new RoutedCommand(nameof(OpenDocumentCommand), typeof(UserControl2));

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    var openDocumentCommandBinding = new CommandBinding(OpenDocumentCommand, ExecutedOpenDocumentCommand, CanExecuteOpenDocumentCommand);
    this.CommandBindings.Add(openDocumentCommandBinding);
  }

  // This is where the globally available functionality must be called.
  // You can implement it directly in MainWindow 
  // or another class that MainWindow can use
  private void ExecutedOpenDocumentCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Hello!");
  }

  // Provide a condition: if result is FALSE the button will be disabled otherwise enabled.
  private void CanExecuteOpenDocumentCommand(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e) 
    => e.CanExecute = true; 
}

MainWindow.xaml
<Window>
  <StackPanel>
    <BarButtonItem Command="{x:Static MainWindow.OpenDocumentCommand}" 
                   Content="Open document" />

    <UserControlOne />
  </Stackpanel>
</Window>

UserControlTwo.xaml
<UserControl>

  <!-- Execute the command and the registered functionality of the MainWindow -->
  <BarButtonItem Command="{x:Static MainWindow.OpenDocumentCommand}" 
                 Content="Open document" />
</UserControl>


Thank you for taking the time and for providing a helpful response. I did click the answer as useful, but I don't have enough points for that to show! Needed to make a few adjustments to get it to work properly and will post my solution later.

Thanks to @BionicCode for pointing me in the right direction, and with the ideas from here.
Here's the solution that is working well.
In my userTwo xaml:
<UserControl.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static custom:userTwo.CustomRoutedCommand}"
        Executed="ExecutedCustomCommand"
        CanExecute="CanExecuteCustomCommand" />
</UserControl.CommandBindings>

In userTwo cs:
public static RoutedCommand CustomRoutedCommand = new RoutedCommand();

public userTwo() 
    {
    InitializeComponent();
    CommandBinding customCommandBinding = new CommandBinding(
        CustomRoutedCommand, ExecutedCustomCommand, CanExecuteCustomCommand);

    this.CommandBindings.Add(customCommandBinding);
    }

    public void ExecutedCustomCommand(object sender,
                                      ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e) {
        MessageBox.Show("Custom Command Executed");
    }

    public void CanExecuteCustomCommand(object sender,
                                        CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e) {
        Control target = e.Source as Control;

        if (target != null) {
            e.CanExecute = true;
        } else {
            e.CanExecute = false;
        }
    }

In my Main Window XAML where I need the method of userTwo to execute add this command to the button:
Command = "{x:Static custom:userTwo.CustomRoutedCommand}"

